# Unit testing by CTest of Cross-compiled Project

Tags: unit-testing, cmake, cross-compiling

I am developing hobby OS which is cross-compiled to other architecture than my development PC and is run in QEMU emulator.

I am trying to introduce unit testing of the source files I develop for my kernel but to let them run on my development machine rather than in QEMU on my target.

In order to cross-compile my sources, I use the toolchain file which uses my custom GCC toolchain. As coming from CMake principle of toolchain file usage, the toolchain file is set up prior to `project(...)` definition in my root `CMakeLists.txt` file.

My question is how to build my test executables for my dev machine (x86_64) using the built-in GCC while cross-compiling my kernel binary for target platform... I do not know how to set `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` / `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` cmake variables specifically for each use case (testing, target build)

To have a look at my particular project, please feel free to navigate here:https://gitlab.com/revolta/revolta

I would like to add `test/` to my project root including selected sources from `source/...` and manage it somehow from my root `CMakeLists.txt`

Thanks in advance for any concept ideas and help! Cheers Martin

Comment: [Toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling) for cross-compiling is specified by `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` variable. Normally, this variable is passed to `cmake` executable, but you may set this variable prior to the `project()` call too. If you set this variable in the `CMakeLists.txt`, then you may set it **conditionally**, dependent on the purpose of the configuration (for building kernel or for building tests).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I tried you approach - setting the usage of toolchain file before setting project(), conditionally. So far so good but now I have the trouble with cmake cache. Once crosscompiling, I set `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` variable within the cache but once I reconfigure for Testing, using native system `g++` (no toolchain file used), the setting of `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` is remembered from previous configuration and the native `g++` is not used. How to manage that? I tried to play with removing the variables from  cache (using `unset( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER CACHE )` but have not solved it...

Comment: Use **different build directories**, for building kernel and and for building tests. That way a cache won't be reused between them.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Is that possible to configure in VS Code? Maybe to set different build directory for each build variant? You know, vs code is triggering my root CMakeLists.txt directly, not using configure.sh script...

Comment: I didn't work with CMake projects under VS Code. From my understanding, it should be a way for create different VS Code projects (with different build directories) from the same CMake project.

Comment: I found a way to push VS Code to build in different directories based on selected CMake Variant. Add the variable to build directory settings - `"cmake.buildDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}/build/${buildType}"` in settings.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is - there is one compiler per configuration. Do not try to make to use two compilers per configuration. Instead run cmake two times and configure it twice,. separately for x86 testing and separately for releasing to target build.

So write a small script (you have `configure.sh` anyway) (I usually write a makefile with all PHONY targets) that would run and build the project twice for two configurations:

```
# ./compile_and_test_your_project.sh

# build for target host
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=the_toolchain -S. -B_build/crosscompiled
cmake --build _build/crosscompiled --target the_main_project_target
( cd _build/crosscompiled && ctest )

# build for native host
cmake -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0" -S. -B_build/native 
cmake --build _build/native --target only_testing_targets
( cd _build/native && ctest )
```

Do not set `CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR` inside cmake config. I advise to try to keep cmake configuration platform agnostic as much as you can and pass platform specific parts using arguments to cofiguration cmake. Such way is scalable - you may use a different toolchain and different environment with ease, or try different compiler options. Inside cmake you can see if you are crosscompiling with just `if (CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)`. Also see `CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR`.

ps. [My makefile](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/yio/-/blob/master/Makefile#L137) from one of my projects that sets different `CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR` depending on make target.

Comment: The most important advise I get from the answer was to build different CMake variant (Build/Release/Test/...) in separate directories as is also visible from this answer. I am using VS Code for my configuration and there I just added `"cmake.buildDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}/build/${buildType}"` in `settings.json` to make it supported in this IDE